# React + Redux-router = Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

My code is working fine, but I have an annoying problem whenever I make a coding mistake and get a runtime error.  For instance, in one of my JSX pages I did `Date()` instead of `new Date()` and instead of reporting the actual error, I got...

```
Uncaught Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.
```

Any error I make almost always shows up as this.  It's being reported from `createStore.js`, which is in my `configureStore.jsx` code below.

Is there a way that I can get better error reporting that helps me identify the real problem?  Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!!!

Here's my setup for reference....

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ReduxRouter } from 'redux-router';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore'
import routes from './routes';

const rootEl = document.getElementById('app-container');

const store = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ReduxRouter routes={routes} />
        </Provider>
    </div>
    , rootEl
);
```

**configureStore.jsx**

```
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { reduxReactRouter } from 'redux-router';

import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';

import rootReducer from '../reducers/rootReducer';
import routes from '../routes';

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}) {

    const history = createHashHistory();

    const middlewares = [
        thunk,
        promiseMiddleware({
            promiseTypeSuffixes: ['PENDING','SUCCESS','ERROR']
        })
    ];

    const toolChain = [
        applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
        reduxReactRouter({
            routes,
            history
        })
    ];

    const store = compose(...toolChain)(createStore)(rootReducer, initialState);

    if (module.hot) {
        module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
            const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/rootReducer');
            store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
        });
    }
    return store;
}
```

**rootReducer.jsx**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerStateReducer } from 'redux-router';
import siteReducer from './siteReducer';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    router: routerStateReducer,
    sites: siteReducer
});
export default rootReducer;
```

**siteReducer.jsx**

```
import {GET_SITES} from '../actions/siteActions';

const defaultState = {
    isPending: null,
    isSuccess: null,
    isError: null,
    error: null,
    data: null
};

export default function siteReducer(state = defaultState, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case `${GET_SITES}_PENDING`:
            return {
                ...defaultState,
                isPending: true
            };
        case `${GET_SITES}_SUCCESS`:
            return {
                ...defaultState,
                isSuccess: true,
                error: false,
                data: action.payload
            };
        case `${GET_SITES}_ERROR`:
            return {
                ...defaultState,
                isError: true,
                error: action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to install all the files locally, and for me it seems to be working fine. Did you try commenting the hot-reload part?

Comment: [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) is pretty good at reporting the correct error. You may create a new project, eject and see what they are doing.

Answer (score 11):

Change the following line:

```
const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/rootReducer');
```

To:

```
const nextRootReducer = require('../reducers/rootReducer').default;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `export const variable_name` instead of `const variable_name` whenever you want to export that variable.

For ex: rootReducer.jsx should be re-written as

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerStateReducer } from 'redux-router';
import siteReducer from './siteReducer';

export const rootReducer = combineReducers({
router: routerStateReducer,
sites: siteReducer
});
export default rootReducer;
```

Note the extra export specifier with const rootReducer

Comment: why would you export it as a named export as well? this doesn't solve anything

Comment: This only changes how you import the reducers later on. Notice how in the store creation the OP imports the `rootReducer` using an unnamed import, meaning the default. Adding the named export wouldn't solve anything unfortunately.

Comment: If it worked for you maybe you were importing your rootReducer by doing `import { rootReducer } from './rootReducer'` maybe?

Comment: Yes, it was the way.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was importing Store from the root reducer path rather than the  actual bundled store root (with devtools on the window and root reducer, middleware being composed, etc).

`import Store from '../../../src/state/Store/reducer';`

changed to

`import Store from '../../../src/state/Store';`